# Why does one need to specify #N/A in the IFNA( ) function of Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

```
=IFNA(#N/A, "Does not exist")
```

I'm a bit confused about the `IFNA()` function in Google Sheets. If I have to specify **#N/A**, what's the difference to `IF()`?

Comment: You can try `=ISERROR()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's say you have a column with values mixed with some #N/A errors... you can either use `IF` like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNA(A:A), 11111, A:A))
```

[image]

or you can make it shorter like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(A:A, 11111))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`IFNA(...,return this)` means "If an `#N/A` error is encountered in the first parameter, return the nicer second parameter rather than the ugly error."

I tend to use `IFERROR(...,return this)` more often, since it catches more errors than just an `#N/A` error.

What fills the `...` above in either formula is generally *some other* formula or expression that alone *might* result in an `#N/A` error or a general error respectively, e.g.:

`=IFERROR(1/A2,"You can't divide by that.")`

Here, if A2 is equal to zero or some string, instead of showing the error in the cell, it will show the alternative return.

Often, the nicer alternative return is omitted altogether, which will just leave the cell null in the case of error rather than displaying the error, e.g.:

`=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2,D2:E,2,FALSE))`

This will return the corresponding value from `E2:E` if whatever is in `A2` is found in `D2:D`. If no match is found, then null will be returned. Without `IFNA( )`, the return would have been `#N/A`.

Or the above could have been structured to include some chosen return like this:

`=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2,D2:E,2,FALSE),"NOT FOUND")`